# Why does my server have an EXP boost?

Tags: tower-of-fantasy

Today when a killed some mobs, I saw a message saying that my server had a 200% boost.

[image: Obtained EXP x208 (This server's multiplier is 200%)]

Why does the server have a boost and what triggered the boost?

Comment: Any kind of special events going on?

Comment: I am not aware of anything. The Side-by-Side event seems to just be an item. https://www.toweroffantasy-global.com/news-detail.html?content_id=4f8c3924a5250a445dab629adddee46f224f

Comment: With the latest errors in-game I wonder if this is some kind of compensation

Comment: I did see posts on their site and Twitter saying they be compensating players for some sort of mishaps, but they didn't say how.

Comment: On my alternate account I am getting 500% xp boost. I think its because I am behind levels on that account, not sure though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some Reddit posts asking the same thing.  While nothing was *definitive*, it seems many believe this is some sort of catch-up mechanism in the game tied to your level and the server age ([this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/TowerofFantasy/comments/wlycgj/dont_make_this_beginner_mistake_of_exp_overflow/) explains the max levels by age of the server).

The first Reddit post is [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/TowerofFantasy/comments/wrls3u/server_xp_multiplier/), where users said the following:

> And apparently its a "catch up mechanic" so people can catch up with the levels

> My best guess is that we are severely underleveled (in terms of levelcap). Hence, the game does not want us to fall behind.

The other Reddit post I found is [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/TowerofFantasy/comments/ws0129/can_someone_explain_the_server_multiplier_to_me/), where people commented:

> Level catch up. XP Multiplier. For example I was 34 when Server level was 41, so I get 500% Added to base XP gained

> When you far behind the cap you get a little help to catch up

The wording of the message might be a bit misleading, because by the sounds of it, not everyone gets this multiplier bonus on the server, only those that are under leveled.  Additionally, the percentage seems to be different for each player, depending on how far behind they are.